# colorbox: send data-attr with post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, colorbox, custom-data-attribute

I'm opening a colorbox (AJAX page) for each link that has the `data-myid` attribute within my selector and I like to send the `data-myid` attribute value with the post request to get the right page back.

```
$(".gallery-media-cover a[data-myid]").colorbox({
    href: 'ajax/view//image',
    data: {
        myid: $(this).attr("data-myid"),
    },
});
```

It works when I just write: `myid: 123` but they are dynamic, so I need to get them from the link. Whenever I try, the `myid` gets posted as undefined when I use `$(this).attr("data-myid")`

I really tried any possible way of getting the data attribute of the url to send it with my request, but none seems to work. I'm 100% sure `data-myid` is in the link.

Also

```
myid: function() {
    return $(this).attr("data-myid");
}
```

and

```
$(this).data("id")
```

stay undefined, I'm really without options here. Can anyone share a light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of the object you provide to the `colourbox()` method `this` does not refer to the link that was clicked on. To achieve what you require you could loop over each link and instantiate the colour box individually:

```
$(".gallery-media-cover a[data-myid]").each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.colorbox({
        href: 'ajax/view//image',
        data: {
            myid: $el.data('myid'),
        },
    });
});
```